# jquery on and off issues

Tags: jquery

I have a button and it is generated dynamically. Initially it has the class "active" when u click on it class changes to "inactive". When u click again it should change to active.

So I have assigned click events using follwoing code.

```
$(".active").on("click",function(){
$(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
});

$(".inactive").on("click",function(){
$(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});
```

Issue is every time first function get called. When I use live instead of on it works fine. How can i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply change `.live` to `.on`,

`$(selector).live(event_type, function(){});`

is same as

`$(document).on(event_type, selector, function(){});`

```
$("body").on("click", '.active', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
});

$("body").on("click", '.inactive', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, that would need a minor change to the HTML would be this:

```
$(function(){    
    $(".toggle").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").toggleClass("inactive");
    });    
});
```

​
This will affect all elements with a `toggle` class assigned to them, and assumes that it will initially have either `inactive` or `active`.

Answer (score 0):

try jquery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

I wrote a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RsYTM/) that demonstrates two ways of achieving the same thing for links. You could do the same for buttons.